# CPU is utilizing 100% resource and therefore Queue failed

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

My code is like below.

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i++) {
    $objUser = [
        "UserName"      =>  $request["UserName"] . $i,
        "EmailAddress"  =>  $request["EmailAddress"] . $i,
        "RoleID"        =>  RoleEnum::ProjectManager,
        "Password"      =>  $request["Password"],
    ];
    $RegisterResponse = $this->Register->Register($objUser);
    $Data = $RegisterResponse["Data"];                
    $job = (new AccountActivationJob($Data));
    dispatch($job);
}
```

Above code is creating 100 users and Each time a queue is being created to send email notification. I am using database default queue.

I have shared hosting account on GoDaddy. Due to some reasons the CPU usage reaches 100. Here is the screenshot.

[image]

Finally loop stops in between. Below is the screenshot after 5 mins.

[image]

Here, My problem is: It is not able to continue creating 100 users. I am doing this to test the sample queue implementation where multiple users send request for registration. Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the findings and found that I should move to VPS instead of Shared hosting. here are the nice and cheap plans by GoDaddy. https://in.godaddy.com/hosting/vps-hosting

[image]

Comment: Consider using an HTTP mail API instead such as Mail Gun. It's free and will not be affected by GoDaddy limits. Laravel also has built-in support for it.

Answer (score 5):

As stated above, GoDaddy has a lot of resource limitations. You can only send 100 Emails an hour is what I have heard.

That also not at a single time. If it detects you are sending a lot of emails, your process is blocked.

Instead, you can queue up the messages to be sent 1 per 20 seconds or 30 seconds. It will help keep the resources in limits, and your emails are sent to the customers without any problem.

You can use the sleep function for this.

Comment: Can u share the code to restrict 10 messages per 10 second?

Comment: You can have a look at the sleep function [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php)

Answer (score 0):

Godaddy does have a limit of resources you can use. If you go over it, it will kill the processes on ssh.

The limits are avaiable [here](https://br.godaddy.com/help/resource-limits-12001)

Try running the php process with a different [nice](https://www.nixtutor.com/linux/changing-priority-on-linux-processes/) parameter.

That's what I do when i need to use an artisan command that does use a lot of resources..

Comment: Actually this is about user registration which is happening at same time by 100 users. How can I prioritize it? This is a same work being performed by 100 users.